Azure OpenAI On Your Data with ElasticSearch - field mapping for content
I am using Azure OpenAI On Your Data via Python, having ElasticSearch as my data source.
Here is the config:
{
    "schema": 1.1,
    "description": "testartu",
    "type": "completion",
    "completion": {
      "model": "gpt-4o-mini",
      "completion_type": "chat",
      "include_history": false,
      "include_input": true,
      "data_sources": [
        {
          "type": "elasticsearch",
          "parameters": {
            "endpoint": "https://mytest.es.westeurope.azure.elastic-cloud.com",
            "index_name": "myindex",
            "authentication": {
              "type": "encoded_api_key",
              "encoded_api_key": "xxxxxx"
            },
            "query_type": "simple",
            "roleInformation": "You are a friendly assistant",
            "fields_mapping": {
              "title_field": "titleText",
              "content_fields": ["contentText","contentText.0", "contentText[0]"]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "stop_sequences": null,
      "temperature": 0.7,
      "top_p": 0.95,
      "max_tokens": 800,
      "input_max_tokens": 128000
    },
    "augmentation": {
      "augmentation_type": "none"
    }
}

The index on ElasticSearch has this (simplified) format:
{
    "titleText": "Here is my title",
    "contentText": ["Here is a lot of text", "here is even more text"]
}

The request to ElasticSearch with this config is successfully searching on the titleText field only. The contentText that contains all the info is never mapped in the response.
My guess is that it is due to the fact contentText is an array of strings and not a string, and the tweaks like contentText.0, contentText[0] don't work.
Any ideas?

Can you please add more details about what is the issue you are facing ?

@SagarPatel poorly explained on my side. I just added more details. Thanks!

did you configured Elasticsearch mapping ? what is data type for contentText in ES ? As per my understanding content_fieldsmust be type of text and it might not allow to configured field which is having values in array.

@SagarPatel Yes, I configured the mapping and contentText is an array of strings (I am reusing an index that is like that, so I cannot concat them all to a single string). I agree content_fields expects text, not an array. That is why I tried the tweaks above like accessing individual elements of the array. I tried contentText.0 and contentText[0] but none of them worked.

ES will not support contentText.0 or contentText[0]. I am not sure how above configuration work and if it is supporting script field. If it is support script field then you can use painless script and read first value of contentText field.

@SagarPatel These are the fields that can be used: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/references/azure-search?tabs=python I cannot see anything similar to a script, so I guess it is impossible to access elements that are not in the root of the index structure in ElasticSearch.

Can you check this link. it seems like there is field call content_fields_separator that you might use and see if it is work for you or not.

@SagarPatel Unfortunately that field is for something else: separating the fields that we manage to fetch from ElasticSearch. In this case, we don't even manage to fetch contentText at all since it is not a string, but an array. I will just leave this question as not possible to fix with current Azure OpenAI settings. Thanks for trying!

Wouldn't it be easier to just create a new field that concatenate the contentText elements into a new field using _update_by_query ?
POST /<index>/_update_by_query
{
"query": {
  "match_all": {}
},
"script": "ctx._source.contentTextConcat = ctx._source.contentText[0] + ' ; ' + ctx._source.contentText[1]"
}

Afterwards, you can just add to content_fields contentTextConcat instead
"schema": 1.1,
    "description": "testartu",
    "type": "completion",
    "completion": {
      "model": "gpt-4o-mini",
      "completion_type": "chat",
      "include_history": false,
      "include_input": true,
      "data_sources": [
        {
          "type": "elasticsearch",
          "parameters": {
            "endpoint": "https://mytest.es.westeurope.azure.elastic-cloud.com",
            "index_name": "myindex",
            "authentication": {
              "type": "encoded_api_key",
              "encoded_api_key": "xxxxxx"
            },
            "query_type": "simple",
            "roleInformation": "You are a friendly assistant",
            "fields_mapping": {
              "title_field": "titleText",
              "content_fields": ["contentTextConcat"]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "stop_sequences": null,
      "temperature": 0.7,
      "top_p": 0.95,
      "max_tokens": 800,
      "input_max_tokens": 128000
    },
    "augmentation": {
      "augmentation_type": "none"
    }
}


Unfortunately I cannot make any changes on ElasticSearch side, I am just the consumer.
